# How to write into ViewData from JS-Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to write some values into ViewData-varables.

```
@ViewData["DestinationId"] = DestinationId;
```

does not work, the script after this line isn't executed anymore.
So what is the right way to fill These kind of variables?
thanks alot

Comment: Won't work. ViewData is evaluated server side, Javascript works cliekt side. Please provide more information on what exactly your requirement is (rather than trying a solution that won't work to a problem you haven't described.

Comment: Thank you, so I found another solution :)